# How do you store the database output in a variable when the SQL statement MAY produce more than 1 row or data

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, row

```
$qry2 = "Select Expertise_Name, Number_Of_Years from expertise e, expertise_particulars ep where Particulars_ID =". $ID ."and e.Expertise_ID = ep.Expertise_ID'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $qry2);
```

I believe that the codes below can not work because it produce more than 1 row.

```
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $ExpertiseName = $row['Expertise_Name'];
        $Years = $row['Number_Of_Years'];
    }

    echo $ExpertiseName;
    echo $Years;
```

Comment: the code works but echo only the last  value

Comment: it does produce more than one row. you're simply continually overwriting your variables with each new rows' data. You need to save the values into an array, or echo them inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eg: a couple of array for store the result

```
$nCnt = 0;
while($row = $result1->mysqli_fetch_assoc())
{
    $ExpertiseName[$nCnt] = $row['Expertise_Name'];
    $Years[$nCnt] = $row['Number_Of_Years'];
    $nCnt++;
}
```

and the a loop for echo

```
for($i; i<count($Years);  $i++) {
   echo $ExpertiseName[$i];
   echo $Years[$i];
}
```

before you should check for the result

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $qry2))){

  $nCnt = 0;
  while($row = $result1->mysqli_fetch_assoc())
  {
    $ExpertiseName[$nCnt] = $row['Expertise_Name'];
    $Years[$nCnt] = $row['Number_Of_Years'];
    $nCnt++;
  }

 for($i; i<count($Years);  $i++) {
   echo $ExpertiseName[$i];
   echo $Years[$i];
  }
}
```

I have slightly correct your query removing end single quote , adding e. to Particulats_ID (hope is righe) and adding a space between $ID and the"and .." clause ..

```
"Select Expertise_Name, Number_Of_Years 
 from expertise e, expertise_particulars ep 
 where e.Particulars_ID = ". $ID ." 
 and e.Expertise_ID = ep.Expertise_ID;";
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard  just the  time for complete .. it.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\XAMMP\htdocs\FYP3\CV.php on line 82.  Got this error. which is the line While($row = $result1 -> fetch_assoc())

Comment: You are sure the query return rows .. you should check for this before

Comment: yes it return 2 rows with 2 column. I have checked it with phpmyadmin. so there is 2 expertise(e.g IT, Business) and number of years for each expertise. this is what they return

Comment: You should use  mysqli_fetch_assoc .. I have update the code anyway

Comment: tried that.. still giving me the same error. not sure whats  wrong:(

Comment: I have update the asnwer with some suggestioon .. try the query i provided

Comment: @scausEdge hmmm i dont think mysqli_fetch_assoc works... the error is Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot before the equal to (.=) so that the values are appended to the variable rather than replacing it in every loop. Add a line break or a comma at the end to separate new data addition.

```
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $ExpertiseName .= $row['Expertise_Name'].'<br>';
    $Years .= $row['Number_Of_Years'].'<br>';
}

echo $ExpertiseName;
echo $Years;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query, see space before `and` clause

```
  $qry2 = "Select Expertise_Name, Number_Of_Years from expertise e, expertise_particulars ep where e.Particulars_ID =". $ID ." and e.Expertise_ID = ep.Expertise_ID";
```

And Change `e.Particulars_ID`  or `ep.Particulars_ID`   where this column is belongs to.